# What is the effect of commenting out async-supported in web.xml of a grails 2.4 project?

Tags: servlets, grails

I am trying to deploy a grails 2.4.4 war file to a weblogic 10.3.6 application server. One of the errors I encountered is that I had to downgrade to the servlet 2.5 xsd from servlet 3.0.

The downgrade meant that the async-supported tag was no longer supported.

Will this adversely affect my grails application from performing correctly?

I learned what it does from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9919831/whats-the-mean-of-async-supported-in-servlet-configure-file-web-xml) but would like to know how it would affect my grails project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless your Grails application makes specific use of Servlet 3.0 features then you won't see any adverse effects. Put simply, this won't effect the base behavior of Grails itself.